# How would you change this function to check XY or YZ instead of just XZ

Tags: javascript, geometry

I have this function that checks in a plane XZ if a point given is inside of the shape given.

Edit: the shape is given by an array of 3D points, so essentially an array of arrays

```js
function pointInShape( pos , shape )
  {
  // ray-casting algorithm based on
  // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
  var is_3d  = pos.length == 3;
  var x      = pos[0];
  var y      = pos[ is_3d ? 2 : 1];
  var inside = false;
  var l      = shape.length;
  var offset = is_3d ? 3 : 2;

  for (var i = 0, j = l - offset; i < l; j = i, i += offset ) 
    {
    var xi = shape[i], yi = shape[i + (is_3d ? 2 : 1)];
    var xj = shape[j], yj = shape[j + (is_3d ? 2 : 1)];
    
    //works by testing an horizontal semi-infinite line starting at P and going to the right
    var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) //first test if it lays in the y range of the segment
        && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi); //then test in which side of the plane it lies
    if (intersect)
        inside = !inside;
    }
  return inside;
  };
```

It doesn't take into account the Y, so for example:
Given a **shape** `s = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]`
Both `pointInShape([0.5, 0, 0.5], s.flat())`
and `pointInShape([0.5, 1, 0.5], s.flat())`    returns `true`.
(notice the flat)

But with a shape s2 = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]], `pointInShape([0.5, 0.5, 0], s2.flat())` returns `false` even if the point is inside the area.

How can I change the function (or create another one) so it also checks the other 2 planes?

Comment: I find that flattening the shape only complicates things

Comment: @MisterJojo I agree, but this is a function that my teacher gave us so I don't know how much I can change it

Comment: your link on www.ecse.rpi.edu is dead

Comment: I don't think a list of points is sufficient to define a shape in 3D. Are you assuming that it is convex? Or will it always be planar? In 2D, it works because you can assume an edge between each point in order and make a polygon. But I think you would need to specify your faces in 3D.